# Android move Image fast and smooth

Tags: android, image, animation, imageview, accelerometer

I want to move my image with the acceleration sensor, so it has to be quite fast and smooth. But I don't know how I can do it the best way. I tried `Canvas` and `TranslateAnimation`, but both weren't fast and smooth enough. Or could the problem also be the `onSensorChanged()` Method from the `SensorEventListener`? Could this be to slow?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide an example of what you have tried, so that others can tell you were you have gone wrong, please.

Answer (score 1):

What is the delay that you have set when registering the sensor? As if you have set SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, then that is not the most ideal for what you are looking to do. I would do SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, or you might even be able to get by with  SENSOR_DELAY_UI.